# Spring Boot 2.1.0 has JUnit5 dependencies, but how to get rid of it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I've just upgraded my projects to use Spring Boot 2.1.0 (before it was 2.0.x)
and i have compilation WARNINGS:

```
[WARNING] Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith': class file for org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith not found
```

I can add dependency org.junit.jupiter / junit-jupiter-api to solve the warning, but I feel it's a 'hack'.

I don't want to see that warning (especially that my projects treat warnings like errors) and I don't want to pollute my projects with unnecessary dependencies.

i'm using Maven, but i can see someone had the same problem with Gradle
https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/9sogxf/spring_boot_210_released_now_with_java_11_support/

Comment: Can you add the POM file to the question?

Comment: Are you using maven/gradle/...?

Comment: Maven, and i've only changed spring-boot version.|

do you want to see 'effective POM' or just for a project? (it'll be hard, as versions are managed by spring and my parent POM)

Comment: someone had the same problem (using gradle) so i guess it;s not a gradle/maven problem
https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/9sogxf/spring_boot_210_released_now_with_java_11_support/

Comment: If you are upgrading your spring boot jar version, then I think you should consider upgrading the versions of the dependencies as well wherever required to maintain backwards compatibility. This would help in the longer run. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: Have you tried excluding JUnit5 from your Spring Boot dependencies in your pom?

Comment: i've tried few artifacts, but i don't know which one exactly. well, i think the problem is that Spring expects some JUnit5 artifacts (Api one), but i don't have ANY junit artifacts in 'effective POM'

Comment: What version of Java are you using? I’ve only ever seen this warning with old versions of Java 8.

Comment: openjdk 1.8.0._181

Comment: The problem is that for example `@DataJpaTest` or `@SpringBootTest` annotations are annotated with `@ExtendWith`, which is part of JUnit 5, so it seems you have to  JUnit 5 API in the classpath even if you are not using it.

Answer (score 9):

If you add the `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api` dependency to your project the warning will go away.
It shouldn't hurt, because it's only API jar and only in test scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `@SpringBootTest` to set `classes=`:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        MyAutoConfiguration.class,
        MyAutoConfigurationIntegrationTest.TestContextConfiguration.class
    })
```

the answer is alluded to in its [api documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html):

> Annotation that can be specified on a test class that runs Spring Boot
>   based tests. Provides the following features over and above the
>   regular Spring TestContext Framework:
>
> Uses SpringBootContextLoader as the default ContextLoader when no specific
>   @ContextConfiguration(loader=...) is defined.
>
> Automatically searches
>   for a @SpringBootConfiguration when nested @Configuration is not used,
>   and no explicit classes are specified.

You can use [`@ContextConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) which does not depend on Junit5's `@ExtendsWith`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class,
    classes = {
        MyAutoConfiguration.class,
        MyAutoConfigurationIntegrationTest.TestContextConfiguration.class
    })
```